# How to turn off Advanced PCB errors in Altium?

Tags: altium

I finished my schematic in Altium and I already debugged all errors and warnings with the "validate PCB" option. Now I want to start with the layout and I went to "Design->Update PCB", so I can import the changes from schematic to PCB. Now I'm getting from the source "Advacned PCB" some errors, that I can't actually cross probe (find in schematic) or make sense of, because I already debugged everything with the validation option. So this might be some wrong setting in the project options, that I'm missing.

Every differential pair I defined is giving the message "Net(s) Not Found in Differential Pair XX : Positive Net [XX_P] & Negative Net [XX_N] in current PCB document". I don't know, what they exactly mean. I can find all the differential pairs under the tab "Nets":

[image]

I'm also supposed to be missing a footprint for one component, but this also not true, since I checked it and I can see the footprint in 2D & 3D:
[image]
Footprint:
[image]

Maybe I have to turn off some stuff from the ECO, but not sure

EDIT:
I actually know how to turn these off in the ECO generation, I wanted to make sure, if this is actually right, because it might affect the design later?
[image]

EDIT 2: A picture for Altium forum for Chris's comment[image]

A snippet from some Differential pairs in my design:
[image]

I also tried without the blanket to directly put the differential pair symbol on the wire, but it didn't make a difference in the errors

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Comment: Is is possible to post part of the schematic showing the differential nets?

Comment: Hello Chris, I tried that. It's giving me the error 'Sorry, the forum is unavailable.' I don't know if this is because my license is only for students. I'm not paying for the license; I have a one-year student subscription.

Comment: @qrk I have around 5-fold hierarchial design, I just showed one kind of differential pair here. If you need more details, let me know